# Choose one in pair from array and find minimum total

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

You receive an array of integers and must choose one value from each pair of adjacent values. For example, given {1,0,5} you can pick 1 and 5 or just 0. The goal is to find the minimum total sum you can get from all the chosen values, print it, and print each chosen value from the array.

For example, given {1,0,5} you want to choose 0 since it's the lowest in the pairs (1,0) and (0,5), and the minimum total sum is 0.

Another example: given {10,30,90,50,30} the minimum sum is 30 + 50 = 80 and we made sure that for each pair of adjacent values at least one was chosen (10,**30**), (**30**,90), (90,**50**), (**50**,30).

I used dynamic programming to find the minimum total sum, but I'm not sure how to print each chosen value to create that sum.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define the input array
        int[] arr = {50, 30, 40, 60, 10, 30, 10};
        // Define the array to store the minimum sum for each index
        int[] dp = new int[arr.length];
        // Initialize the first element of the dp array
        dp[0] = arr[0];
        dp[1] = arr[1];
        // Loop over the input array from the second index to the last index
        int choice1 = 0, choice2;
        for(int i = 2; i<arr.length; i++) {
            // Choose the previous index and add its minimum sum to the current element
             choice1 = dp[i-1] + arr[i];
            // Choose the index before the previous index and add its minimum sum to the current element
             choice2 = dp[i-2] + arr[i];
            // Compare the two choices and choose the one with the lower sum
             dp[i] = Math.min(choice1, choice2);
        }
        // Print the minimum sum and the chosen values
        if(dp[arr.length - 1] > dp[arr.length - 2]) {
            System.out.println(dp[arr.length - 2]);
        }else {
            System.out.println(dp[arr.length - 1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the link to the problem or simply paste the full instructions if the problem is not available online? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Please add an example of what the wished output would be for your code. Do you just want to print the minimum sum, or do you want to print which numbers add up to the minimum sum, or do you want to print the indices of those numbers, or ..... multiple examples would be best.

Comment: I want to print both the minimum sum and the numbers used to find it.

Comment: In order to answer your query, try managing one more array for keeping track of transition like you got to min i from where: i-1 or i-2. Then you can reverse travel this array to find the numbers involved.